# TokenMismatchException when refreshing token in passport laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-passport

I have recently followed the official documentation on how to properly install and setup Laravel Passport in a demo application (blog).

My routes are set up following [these](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#installation) instructions:

> Next, you should call the Passport::routes method within the boot
>   method of your  AuthServiceProvider. This method will register the
>   routes necessary to issue access tokens and revoke access tokens,
>   clients, and personal access tokens:

While using Postman to run some sample requests I noticed that ***oauth/token/refresh*** route requires a CSRF token.

Running artisan route:list I got:

```
|        | POST     | oauth/token                             |                  | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController@issueToken        | throttle     |
|        | POST     | oauth/token/refresh                     |                  | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\TransientTokenController@refresh        | web,auth     |
```

Any ideas on how to properly refresh the token?

Comment: You have the refresh route set to use the `web` middleware when it shouldn't.

Comment: I registered the routes using the `Passport::routes`, as described in the documentation. Would that be a bug?

Comment: It's not a bug. Where did you call `Passport::routes()`? It should be in `routes\api.php` not `routes\web.php`

Comment: @jfadich, I've updated the question using a reference to the source I am using to register routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSRF can be disabled for desired URI-s, as stated on https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf. For an example, I've added one value as URL path in $except property in VerifyCsrfToken class:

```
protected $except = [
    'oauth/authorize',
];
```

and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. To settle this once and for all... If you are on laravel 5.3+ and you are having to comment the  `App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class` in `$middlewareGroups` at `App\Http\Kernel.php`. You are an intergalactic documentation-read avoider and you deserve to be persued and brought to justice by supergirl :-(

## JustKidding. We all get caught up.

Puns aside, there's a better solution, and it's obvious and it goes like this.
Taylor created three files for routes namely `web`, `console` and `api`.

Then Taylor went ahead and created a comment just before the `protected $middlewareGroup` line in Kernel.php to say `The application's route middleware groups.`.  Then he separated the middleware groups as `web` and `api`.

So if you look at the `web` $middlewareGroup... It contains the `VerifyCsrfToken::class`, but the `api` middleware group does not. The answer has been in front of us guys!
Therefore if you put your route in the `api.php` file under the routes folder then you will never have csrf verification and your normal forms can still have csrf protection as long as their corresponding routes are in the `web.php` routes file.

Almost always when a solution is involving commenting out the `\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class` it usually is almost always from lack of proper study the route structure in laravel 5.3+.

There was a significant shift from the prior versions with regards to having only 1 unified routes file vs a split routes file. The split routes files were created solely to enable separate application of middleware.

Hope this helps someone one day.

Answer (score -2):

what i did last time was to disable CSRF from kernel.php, i don't really know if this is best practice but i comment out:

```
 App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class
```

Comment: this is not recommended as it leave your application vulnerable to csrf (amongst others ?) attack